# Cutting a mesh and preserve texture

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

Good day

I have a **plane** with **texture** and **normal map**.

I want to cut it with the **split tool** and **apply a volume** with the **solid modifier**

but when cutting the solid, one of its cut parts **shines** and when exporting the textures they look of different shades.

the problem is when I want to separate the parts, with split "Y"

What could I do to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried triangulating the ngons?

Comment: put a screenshot of your normal map and your UV map. maybe your unwrap is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### cut your mesh in QUADS

[image]

### UNWRAP again

[image]

### add the solidify modifier, and apply

[image]

### after this do the following

1. Save you Blend
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Apply **SCALE** and **ROTATION**

to return the value of the scale to one

4. save your blend again to update all

### separate PIECES !!

**see the screencast key in the gif**

*Step 1*
[image]

*Step 2*
[image]

*Step 3*
separate the pieces one by one until completing this

NOTE: it is very likely that you have to adjust your uv map of each of the pieces because you have separated them and you have added new faces, you can use the same texture just place the uv in the place where the part that should texture your texture is, worth phrase redundancy
[image]
Remember remove dobles before you separate the piece

[image]

*Step 4*
repeat the process in each piece until you complete everything

[image]

### another way to separate the pieces

[image]

**obtain this**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how do I separate the parts? I want to make an animation where the box is broken into parts and I have that model with flat mesh

Comment: I am at work in singing I quit work I will put you how to do it ok

Comment: ok.. it's ready, add what you asked for @DennisArcos don't forget to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Thanks is what i wanted.

Comment: It is a pleasure to have helped you